# How do you make the endpoints of a diagonal line straight?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient, pathfinder, pen-tool

[image]

I have to make a gradient "V" using the pen tool, but the endpoints are slightly slanted and I want to make the start point and end point look like the image on the right, which is clean and straight.

I've tried doing "outline stroke" and then cutting off the top using pathfinder, but illustrator won't let me cut off a gradient shape.

What should I do?

Comment: The diagonal lines are straight. If you want to customize them then use the direct select tool

Comment: I mean the start point and end point is not straight if you see the image on the left.. I want to make it look like image on the right!

Comment: They are straight perpendicular. If you want to customize them then use the Direct Select tool.

Comment: I tried using the direct select tool, but then the whole "V" is moving :(( I just want to cut off the top to make it look like that right one.

Comment: Pathfinder's Shape Mode: Minus Front should work on an outlined stroke. I tried it here.

Comment: The pathfinder minus front won't work on gradient :(((( HELP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If the path is a stroke**

Make a square that cuts off the top part of the V shape. You do not need a fill or stroke for the square. Select both, go to Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make.

**If the path is expanded**

You can use the direct select tool and manually move the inner-endpoints down.

OR

Make a square that cuts off the top part of the V shape.

[image: Top of the v shape]

Open the pathfinder window (Window -> Pathfinder). With both objects selected, pick the Crop option. You could also pick Divide and then delete the top part of the V.

Result

[image: End result]